# How to compare the database table particular column with respective string

Tags: mysql, bash, sqlite

I want to compare the particular column value in the database table with respective input strings in the shell script. How can I do this?
In the following script I want to read the all customer values but it only reads the first value only. What can I do?

`customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name"); 
    if [[ $c_name != $customer ]];`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename

echo " --- enter the table name --- "
read table_name

sqlite3 $databasename.db "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"

sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);"


echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---"
read cus_count


echo "--- Enter the following details one by one---"

port_num=8080

for((i=1;i<=cus_count;i++))
do


echo "enter the $i customer details"

echo "---Enter the customer name---"
read c_name

customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name");


if [[ $c_name != $customer ]];

then
    echo "---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---"
    read c_status

if [[ "$port_num" == "$port_num" ]]; then
       port_num=$(($port_num + 1))

c_domain="$c_name"


sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.in\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;" 
fi


else
    echo "!!!OOPS you entered customer name already available!!!"
    echo "---Please enter new customer name---"

i=$(($i - 1))

fi
done
done

echo " --- Records from the $table_name ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name;"
```

Comment: Please put only the relevant parts of your code in question.

Comment: customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name");
if [[ $c_name != $customer ]];
then
   ----

Comment: I already saw that piece of code in question. I just meant to say only that piece was sufficient to reproduce the problem. Also, I have added a solution for your particular problem

Comment: if i give the first value as "ABC" then second value same as "ABC" it shows the Warning message correctly .but if i give first value as "ABC" second value as "BCD" and again the third value as "ABC" now it not displays the warning message its my problem...!

Comment: A side note: You need to put the `declare -a` before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bash array

```
declare -a customer_list
customer_list=( "$(sqlite3 "$databasename".db "select cus_name from $table_name")" )
```

Then do

```
for customer  in "${cus_array[@]}"
do
 if [[ "$c_name" != "$customer" ]]
 then
 ..
 fi
done
```

Comment: @Mahendranatarajan can you do `echo "${customer_list[@]}"` just after `customer_list=( "$(sqlite3 "$databasename".db "select cus_name from $table_name")" )` just to see the array is rebuild correctly.

Comment: it displays only last 3 values only not fully

Comment: @Mahendranatarajan   Can you enter about 5 values and then try?

Comment: ya i give five values only but it shows recent 3 values

Comment: did u know tamil ah]